# Converting charAt check 'containing A-Z' to 'not containing A-Z'

Tags: java, netbeans, compare, charat

I would like to check if a String input contains characters other than alphabets. Below is my current code:

```
if ((name.charAt(i) >= 'a' && name.charAt(i) <= 'z') ||
 ((name.charAt(i) >= 'A' && name.charAt(i) <= 'Z')))
```

How can I change the code such that it functions as check if `name.charAt(i)` "is not equals to `A` to `Z` OR `a` to `z`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just negate your condition :

```
if (!((name.charAt(i) >= 'a' && name.charAt(i) <= 'z') || ((name.charAt(i) >= 'A' && name.charAt(i) <= 'Z'))))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    String str = "1234";
    if(!str.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")){
        System.out.println("not contains alphabets");
    }else{
        System.out.println("contains alphabets");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll demonstrate a systematic approach to this which can help you in other similar situations. First, to improve readability, extract the char to a local var.

```
char ch = name.charAt(i);
if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z' || ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') ...
```

Now you can work with this in terms of DeMorgan's laws. To make things easier, I'll declare some helper boolean vars for each part:

```
boolean a = ch >= 'a', 
        z = ch <= 'z', 
        A = ch >= 'A', 
        Z = ch <= 'Z';
```

So, we have your original expression as

```
(a && z) || (A && Z)
```

We want the negative of that expression:

```
!(a && z || A && Z)
```

Let's clean it up. Apply

[image: \neg(P\lor Q)\iff(\neg P)\land(\neg Q)]

to get

```
 !(a && z) && !(A && Z)
```

Then apply

[image: \neg(P\land Q)\iff(\neg P)\lor(\neg Q)]

to the inner expressions:

```
(!a || !z) && (!A || !Z)
```

Now substitute the original expresions back in, negating `<=` into `>`, `>=` into `<`:

```
(ch < 'a' || ch > 'z') && (ch < 'A' || ch > 'Z')
```

this is the negated expression you are looking for, cleaned up of any explicit negations.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of comparing characters for upper & lowercase, use Character.isLetter(char c) method as it checks for both the cases.

```
    char[] chars = name.toCharArray();
         boolean isAlphabet = true;
        for (char c : chars) {
           if (!Character.isLetter(c)) {
               //if character is not A-Z or a-z
                isAlphabet = false;
                    }
    }
```